# How to use screen with mysql import

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, mysql, import

I need to import a very large MySQL table on remote server. Usually I'm using

```
mysql -u mysql_user -pMypass db_name < sql_data.sql
```

But it takes about 5 hours to complete the task. I tried using nohup but the logout process is killing the import. I found that I could use screen, but without any luck.

```
screen -dmS import_table mysql -u mysql_user -pMypass db_name < sql_data.sql
```

Please suggest what else I can try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invoke `screen` at a shell prompt. After it's started the shell inside `screen`, then run the `mysql` import command as normal. To detach from the screen session, type Ctrl-A, D.
To reattach the session, type `screen -r`

Comment: It's not as simple as that, mysql commands for many version do not do well with window resizing (like what happens when dettaching a screen) so the process stops with SIGWINCH.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62578

Comment: As odd as it sounds in another shell before detaching screen you can try `killall -WINCH mysql` and then detach your screen session.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95127/problems-with-resizing-terminal

Comment: Nice catch.  "tmux" also does everything screen does, and more.

Comment: Thanks @John. I eventually used byobu, so your advise helped a lot!